# Creating Payment Request works in simulator, but not on a real device

Tags: ios, xamarin, stripe-payments, applepay

I integrated the Stripe component in my app and using Apple Pay for accepting payments.

I tested it on iPhone 6 and iPhone 6 plus, and the devices have valid cards. But If I try to create a payment request `StripeClient.CanSubmitPaymentRequest` is always returning false in real device. It is working fine in simulator.

http://components.xamarin.com/view/stripe

I followed all the steps which are provided above.

I have to add anything else. Please help me to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Issue is I added the merchant id as string value of that key(com.apple.developer.in-app-payments) in entitlement. After I changed as the merchant id in array item of that key(com.apple.developer.in-app-payments) in entitlement its working fine. screencast.com/t/mfW7CABNuxE

Thanks for your support.

Comment: To run apple pay in real device did you add any test cards or real cards to it?

Answer (score 0):

Have you created a merchant ID on the Apple developer portal, provided a certificate for that ID, and enabled the required entitlements inside your project?

Comment: I have created the merchant ID in apple developer portal and I have created the "apple pay"  certificate for that merchant id.

I didn't add any entitlement in xamarin studio regarding apple pay. Where to add and what to add?

entitlement was not mentioned in xamarin component store.


Can you please help me to solve this.

Comment: Apple Pay requires your app to be entitled with the merchant ID you created. I've not used Xamarin, so I couldn't tell you how it handles entitlements. In Xcode you'd need to add the correct entitlement into your entitlements plist, or use the Capabilities window (which will do it automatically for you).

Comment: I added the entitlement for xamarin keyname as "com.apple.developer.in-app-payments"(not my appID. it was told in xamarin support)  and string values as "My merchant ID"
It occurs the same problem after adding too(StripeClient.CanSubmitPaymentRequest) returns false.

Comment: The Issue is I added the merchant id as string value of that key(com.apple.developer.in-app-payments) in entitlement. After I changed as the merchant id in array item of that key(com.apple.developer.in-app-payments) in entitlement its working fine.

http://screencast.com/t/mfW7CABNuxE   
           
Thanks for your support